"Your last edit was rejected"-warning does not appear on MSE
As of writing, my last suggest-edit on MSE has been rejected:

As per the last community sprint changing the implementation of Tell users when their edits are rejected,
I should receive this banner:

However, I only see the regular banner:


MSE version: rev 2024.10.11.16802
Browser used: Firefox 131.0, Replicated on Firefox Developer Edition 132.0b6
Replication: Possible after reload (CRTL+SHIFT+R) I could only test this for MSE as it is the only place where my last edit has been rejected.


While at it, I would like to recommend additionally implementing a notification for rejected edits as originally asked. See also: Show rejections in the achievements-dialog as the current implementation is highly inefficient.

Maybe it's only on Stack Overflow, and not network wide. (It was asked for, after all, in a per-site meta i.e. only for one specific site)

@ShadowWizard I don't think so, as the blue banner should be part of the change. In the original answer, you can see a screenshot of the old, yellow design for the info banner.
